# Twig does not update changes in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am working with Symfony 2.8 in developer mode and Windows 10. When I update template Twig, always I have to clear cache to update render. I looked permissions for folders cache and logs and I have the necessary permissions.

Any help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to app config file (by defualt will be located in `../app/config/config.yml` from your root directory). Scroll to the twig configuration settings (under twig:) and change the cache value (which should be pointing to the cache directory) to false like so:

```
twig:
    cache:  false
```

*If you do not see any cache configuration entry, simply add the line above.*

Or you can disable the twig cache on `web/app_dev.php` only for avoid any problem when you're going to push your code in prod environnement.

Comment: My 5 cents - after doing the change, restart webserver (probably Apache) and clear the cache manually.

Comment: @Nick that is not practical at all if you do many changes frequently while developing.
the suggested answer to deactivate the cache works great. Just make sure to do this within the dev twig configuration rather than the global one for all environments.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to execute the command below in terminal, in your symfony project directory.

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

Symfony documentation about that:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html